# I have a function that works and would like to run it in a loop for multiple data frames from a list but don't know how to update the dataframes?

Tags: r, lapply

I have a line of code that works

```
df$col_new<-sprintf('%03s', substring(df$col1, nchar(df$col1) - 2))
```

I want to run it in a loop

```
lapply(List, function(x) {
assign(x,
     get(x) %>%
       mutate(col_new = sprintf('%03s', substring(col1, nchar(col1) - 2))))
} )
```

I get the results in the console but not in the dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

Try any of the two:

```
for(i in seq_along(List)){
  List[[i]][["col_new"]] <- sprintf('%03s', substring(List[[i]][["col1"]], nchar(List[[i]][["col1"]]) - 2))
}

List <- lapply(List, function(x){
  x[["col_new"]] <- sprintf('%03s', substring(x[["col1"]], nchar(x[["col1"]]) - 2))
  x
})
```

Comment: I got an error message  Error in x[["col1"]] : subscript out of bounds  and Error in List[[i]][["col1"]] : subscript out of bounds

Comment: @user35131 Do you have a column named `col1`?

Comment: I'm running this script through 16 different dataframes. Maybe one doesn't have. I'll check.

Comment: col1 exists for all 16 data frames and the data types are all "int". There are some NA values but i don't think that should affect anything. I ran them individually using the line of code, but can't get in the loop.

Comment: @user35131 If in the `for` loop if you put `print(head(List[[i]][["col1"]]))` what is the output? And `print(names(List[[i]]))`?

Comment: Error in List[[i]] : subscript out of bounds

Comment: @user35131 I'm puzzled, `seq_along(List)` runs through all elements of the list and only those. Try `sapply(List, is.null)` then.

Comment: yes same. In seq_along(List) i had the total count with no gaps. then for sapply i had all value in the list say false

Comment: @user35131 Maybe `List[[i]]$col_new`? I'm running out of ideas :(.

Comment: yes i understand. same subscript out of bounds. I have to do a deeper check then.

Comment: @user35131 What does `for(i in seq_along(List)) print(head(List[[i]]))` give?

Comment: That gave me the written values in the list sequentially one after the other

Comment: @user35131 Can you post, say, `print(head(List[[1]]))` in an edit to the question?